# Comments are not working on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, comments

[image]
[image]

Looks like that everything is set then why the comments are not appearing on the Custom Post types single posts?

can some one please help me.

Comment: Check if the comments template is being called from the single CPT template.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: As I can see in your other comment, you are using `single-videp.php` to display single CPT. Do you have the `comments_template();` call anywhere in that file?

Answer (score 1):

you could try 2 things.

Look under screen options on the custom post type edit page and make sure that comments is checked.  You have the options likely but the visibilty is currently hidden.

If that doesn't work, you could try:

In SETTINGS > DISCUSSION uncheck the "Allow people to post comments on new articles" setting.
Click "Save Changes"
Now go back and re-check "Allow people to post comments on new articles"
Click "Save Changes"

UPDATE:

If you're using a custom single, then you'll need to include the comments function on your template.  Did you do that?  Often it's better to start with the normal single.php, rename  copy and then make your customizations.

Comment: Tried not working. Do we need to make any changes [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/Ix9dbWvjN)

Comment: are you using a custom template for your cpt or using a theme single.php?

Comment: Yes single-video.php

Comment: Does your template even include the comments template?

Comment: I have a customized template like [this one](https://tinyurl.com/y8takfje) in functions.php → I thought CPT's will automatically take it like it was taken by default single.php

Comment: Look at any of the default themes' single.php, they include comments with the `comments_template()` function. Are you doing that?

Comment: if you're using a custom single, then as jacob said you'll need to include the comments function on your template.  DId you do that?  Often it's better to start with the normal single.php, rename  copy and then make your customizations.

Comment: There is an issue the comment form is customized in functions.php through Comment Call Back Function. How to make sure that when we are using `comments_template()` the "Comment Call Back Function" should be taken into account. In single.php it is automatically working - the customized version, without even using the comments_template().